# BinarySearch by Tolerance

Tags: java

I am trying to do a binary search with tolerance value of 0.1 but I keep getting this compilation error there is no such method Math.abs(boolean). When I googled it stack suggested to use two Math.abs,but that also did not work. Please help me with this.I am stuck at this point for a long time

```
                   final double TOLERANCE = 0.1;                        
                   else if(time==r[mid])
                 {
                     System.out.println("found"+mid);
                     return Math.abs(r[mid])-Math.abs(r[mid-1])<TOLERANCE);

                 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The one with no compilation error would read

```
return (Math.abs(r[mid]) - Math.abs(r[mid-1])) < TOLERANCE;
```

The brackets I've added may not be necessary, but they add clarity.

I think that calculation is still wrong. Here's it with more clarity and a better method.

```
double difference = r[mid] - r[mid-1];
return Math.abs(difference) < TOLERANCE;
```

The abs is on the difference, so it doesn't matter whether it's a positive or negative result of the substraction.

That said, is the Math.abs even necessary if your items are ordered?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part `Math.abs(r[mid-1]<TOLERANCE)`.  You are trying to get an absolute value from the result of a boolean expression.

Comment: So the bracket should be before the <

Comment: the result of `r[mid-1]<TOLERANCE` is a `boolean` so that can't work.  Perhaps you meant `Math.abs(r[mid-1])` and put the bracket in the wrong spot?  It's unclear to me what you are trying to do with the `TOLERANCE` test so I don't think I can tell you where the `<` _should_ be.

Comment: I am tryong to search for 9.4 and if it finds something like 9.3 it should return value found at that index

Comment: sorry the bracket is a typo

Comment: @ananymous59: Do you still get the error after correcting the typo?

Comment: I'm guessing the correct code is `Math.abs(r[mid] -r[mid-1]) < TOLERANCE`. This is a common method of comparing doubles for equality by checking if they're fairly close to each other.

Comment: @ananymous59 You edited the code in your question, and you added the close parenthesis, but you didn't take the other one away. The only way you'd get the same error is if you have the same syntax error in your code elsewhere. Please make a habit of including the full error message with line number.